# Sorting and accessing tuples in lists by the element at a given index

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list and I would like to sort the tuples in the list based on the second index.

```
data = [[(7, -1), (8, 10), (9, 5), (10, 0.1), (11, -0.4)], [(7, -3), (8, -1), (9, 2), (10, 0.4), (11, -0.2)]]

sorted_by_second = sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1])

print(sorted_by_second)
```

which results in:

```
[[(7, -3), (8, -1), (9, 2), (10, 0.4), (11, -0.2)], [(7, -1), (8, 10), (9, 5), (10, 0.1), (11, -0.4)]]
```

But I am trying to get:

```
[[(7, -1), (11, -0.4), (10, 0.1), (9, 5), (8, 10)], [(7, -3), (8, -1), (11, -0.2), (10, 0.4), (9, 2)]]
```

And I also want to extract cells for special condition:

1. when the second index in the cells are equal to -1

Take `[(7, -1), (8, 10), (9, 5), (10, 0.1), (11, -0.4)]` for example, `(7, -1)` is the one that I want.

2. when the second index values are the smallest and second smallest.

Take `[(7, -1), (8, 10), (9, 5), (10, 0.1), (11, -0.4)]` for example, after sorting -> `[(7, -1), (11, -0.4), (10, 0.1), (9, 5), (8, 10)]` -> it is clear to see that for second index in the tuples, 0.1 and 5 are the smallest and second smallest positive values. Therefore, `(10, 0.1), (9, 5)` are what I want.

Like:

```
[[(7, -1), (10, 0.1), (9, 5)], [(8, -1), (10, 0.4), (9, 2)]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You are expecting two outputs. Can you explain more on your second output?

Comment: Can you explain the second part of what you need? "And I also want to extract cells for special condition: when the second index in the cells are equal to -1, and when the second index values are the smallest and second smallest" This sentence isn't clear.

Comment: @ Austin @Dekel I edit my question, please take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt on sorting failed because you have list of lists so you were referring the inner lists while saying `tuple`. You need to go one more layer down, then do the sorting, like this:

```py
data = [
    [(7, -1), (8, 10), (9, 5), (10, 0.1), (11, -0.4)],
    [(7, -3), (8, -1), (9, 2), (10, 0.4), (11, -0.2)]
]
sorted_by_second = [sorted(l, key = lambda tup: tup[1]) for l in data]
print(sorted_by_second)
```

For the second part of your question, what you are looking for is `filter`. First define the conditions: second index should be either -1 or greater than 0. Then we can simply pick the first 3 values from the result.

```py
filtered = [list(filter(lambda tup: tup[1] == -1 or tup[1] > 0, l))[: 3]
    for l in sorted_by_second
]
print(filtered)
```

```
[[(7, -1), (10, 0.1), (9, 5)], [(8, -1), (10, 0.4), (9, 2)]]
```

Comment: Hi, I ran your code, but I got error. TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: The above snippet works without any error. There must be something wrong with your code. In which line does the error occur? What is your initial data?

Answer (score 1):

Your list is actually a list of lists, so you will need to sort each sub-list:

```
data = [[(7, -1), (8, 10), (9, 5), (10, 0.1), (11, -0.4)], [(7, -3), (8, -1), (9, 2), (10, 0.4), (11, -0.2)]]
sorted_by_second = [sorted(x, key=lambda tup: tup[1]) for x in data]
sorted_by_second

[[(7, -1), (11, -0.4), (10, 0.1), (9, 5), (8, 10)],
  [(7, -3), (8, -1), (11, -0.2), (10, 0.4), (9, 2)]]
```